# Using CSS to resize Tumblr Header globally?

Tags: css, tumblr

Really new to CSS here...

I'm trying to resize with CSS the background image to fit the header.
So far I've tried wrapping the image itself with a div class to try to manipulate it... to no avail!

HTML:

```
{block:ShowHeaderImage}<div class="header-image"><img src="{HeaderImage}" alt=""></div>{/block:ShowHeaderImage}
```

CSS:

```
.header-image   {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: -1;
    opacity: .05;
    background-image: url({HeaderImage});
}
```

There are other elements in the header, hence the background-position.

I've successfully gotten it to resize by putting the background image in the parent class -- however then the header image is not toggleable via the {block:ShowHeaderImage} function, nor can I change the opacity of JUST the background image as far as I know.

I'm probably making a few mistakes here but the end goal is to have it resizeable and toggling using Tumblr's syntax.

Comment: I don't believe `background-position: -1;` is valid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 1):

#### Custom Images

You can check if a custom image has been *uploaded*, using an `if` operator:

```
{block:IfHeaderImage}<div class="header-image"><img src="{HeaderImage}" alt=""></div>{/block:IfHeaderImage}
```

#### Custom Text

You can use custom text to provide a value for the *opacity*:

```
<meta name="text:Header Opacity" content="0.5"/>

.header-image   {
    opacity: {text:Header Opacity};
    background-image: url({HeaderImage});
}
```

**References**

Theme Options - https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#theme-options